# IsotopeJS + Phonegap:Android overlapping isotope items

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-isotope

I'm using Phonegap to deploy a project to iOS and Android tablets, IsotopeJS is being used for laying out an app's image based menu.

The relevant code is here in JSFiddle, there is one notable difference, in that MainMenuInit() is being called in response to the DeviceReady event, whereas here it is called from document.ready.

> http://jsfiddle.net/TLQ6q/2/

```
function MainMenuInit() {
    var $container = $('.isotopeMenu');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        ResizeMainMenuTiles();
    });
}

function ResizeMainMenuTiles() {
    console.log("Resizing Menu");
    var $container = $('.isotopeMenu');
    var $height = 250;


    $container.isotope({
        width: 1024,
        height: 768,
        itemSelector: ".isotopeItem",
        layoutMode: 'masonryHorizontal',
        masonryHorizontal: {
            rowHeight: $height,
            gutterWidth: 0
        }
    });

}
```

It correctly lays out the items in the fiddle, but when deployed via Phonegap to my Android device the isotope menu is collapsed, with all the items overlaid at the same position.

Here's a screenshot from the device

> http://postimg.org/image/lcsoompyl/

Debugging on the device throws no obvious errors out to logCat.

Answer (score 0):

There a two tricking things I have found using isotope which BTW I still have not mastered.

### Set the width and height of the images

Try to **set the width and height of the images** from the beginning if you can or programmatically and refresh your content wrapper if the latest method is used.

```
<img src="img-file.jpg" width="280" height="160" />
```

From the isotope documentation:

> Most layout modes (i.e masonry, fitRows) need to measure the size of
>   each item to appropriately account for its space in the layout.
>   Unloaded media files like images and @font-face fonts can throw off
>   layout and cause item elements to overlap one another. Ideally,
>   Isotope layouts should be initialized after all inner content has
>   loaded.

### Isotope initialization after media loaded

Try to **initialize** isotope once you are sure that all the media content has been loaded. Isotope provide one method and recommend another one.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#images

*Extracted from the doc, but be sure to check the official one in the link above.*

The next best solution is to use the **imagesLoaded** plugin included with Isotope. It’s a small plugin that finds all the images in a context, and fires a callback function once all the images have loaded.

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.isotope({
    // options...
  });
});
```

**$(window).load()**
Another solution is to initialize Isotope inside $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready(). This will trigger Isotope after all the media on the page has loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#container').isotope({
    // options...
  });
});
```

Hope it helps and let us know how it works.

Comment: Perhaps you should check out the fiddle before answering, both of those  things are already covered